# Oracle SQL DATA_TYPE CHAR(8 BYTE) query as number using index TO_NUMBER

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an oracle SQL database where there is a column called `SESID` which has a `DATA_TYPE` of `CHAR(8 BYTE)`. We have an index set up on this column, however when I have a look at the execution plan, we appear not to be using the index. The simple query that I would be using is

`SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE SESID = 12345`

Having a look at the execution plan it is not using the index because it has to do a `TO_NUMBER` call on the `SESID` column, this prevents oracle from considering the index in the query plan.

Here is the execution plan information which details this:

```
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------    
1 - filter(TO_NUMBER("SESID")=12345)
```

My question is this, is there any way to change the query so that it considers the number '12345' as a CHAR Array? My intuition told me that this might work:

```
SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE SESID = '12345'
```

But it obviously did not... Does anybody know how I could do this

I'm using the standard OracleClient provided in .NET 4 to connect to the oracle DB and run the query.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE SESID = '12345'` should work, if there is an index on sesid, AND there is enough data in the table for Oracle to think that an index is a good idea.  The fact that an index exists and *could* be used does not guarantee that it *will* be used.  If you want to find out why you need to do a LOT of reading up on the "cost based optimizer"

Comment: `WHERE SESID = '12345'` is the correct way to do it. What exactly do you mean that with "*obviously it did not work*"?

Comment: I would not be asking the question if it had worked :) I'm using the standard OracleClient connection provider in .NET 4 to run the query. I probably should have mentioned that in my question. `WHERE SESID = '12345'` does not work, it returns no results.

Comment: So `WHERE sesid = 12345` returns results, but `WHERE sesid = '12345'` returns nothing?  Can you supply the table definition and an INSERT statement for the row that does not get returned?

Comment: It returns no results because the column is `CHAR(8 BYTE)` and has been right padded with spaces until it is 8 characters in length. `WHERE SESID = '12345XXX'` should work (where `X` is a space character) and so should `WHERE SESID = RPAD( TO_CHAR( 12345 ), 8, ' ' )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d465c/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl ( SESID CHAR(8 BYTE) );

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ( '1' );
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ( '12' );
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ( '123' );
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ( '1234' );
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ( '12345' );
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ( '123456' );
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ( '1234567' );
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ( '12345678' );
```

**Query 1**:

A `CHAR` column will right pad the string with space characters. You can see this with the following query:

```
SELECT SESID, LENGTH( SESID ), LENGTH( TRIM( SESID ) )
FROM   tbl
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d465c/4/0)**:

```
|    SESID | LENGTH(SESID) | LENGTH(TRIM(SESID)) |
|----------|---------------|---------------------|
| 1        |             8 |                   1 |
| 12       |             8 |                   2 |
| 123      |             8 |                   3 |
| 1234     |             8 |                   4 |
| 12345    |             8 |                   5 |
| 123456   |             8 |                   6 |
| 1234567  |             8 |                   7 |
| 12345678 |             8 |                   8 |
```

**Query 2**:

This query explicitly converts the number to a character string:

```
SELECT SESID
FROM   tbl
WHERE  SESID = TO_CHAR( 12345 )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d465c/4/1)**:

However, the `SESID` you want to match is `12345___` (where `___`represents the three trailing spaces) and does not equal `12345` (without the trailing spaces) so no rows are returned.

**Query 3**:

Instead you can ensure that the number is padded to the correct length when it is converted to a character string:

```
SELECT SESID
FROM   tbl
WHERE  SESID = RPAD( TO_CHAR( 12345 ), 8, ' ' )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d465c/4/2)**:

```
|    SESID |
|----------|
| 12345    |
```

**An Alternative Solution**

Change the column definition from `CHAR(8 BYTE)` to `VARCHAR2(8)` then you can use query 2 without issues.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE SESID = '12345'`

or

`SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE SESID = TO_CHAR( 12345 )`

Oracle is slightly odd in that it if you compare a literal to a column that requires an implicit type conversion it will **always** try to convert the column instead of the literal.

It's worth watching out for on every SQL statement, and adding an explicit conversion on the literal to make sure that you don't get caught out.

Having said this, having an index and a SQL statement that *could* use one does not guarantee that Oracle *will* use it - there also needs to be enough data in the table for Oracle to think and index will be of use.

If you want to find out why you need to do a LOT of reading up on the "cost based optimizer"

**Aside:**

If you find that you *can't* do a conversion on the literal for some reason (e.g. the sql is generated by a library over which you have no control) then you *can* create a functional index.

I.E. an index that is based on the conversion that will take place.

E.g. `CREATE index test_table_index on ( TO_NUMBER( sesid ) )`

This would only be possible if all data in `sesid` is numeric.

Which raises the point that when the column is converted it may convert more data than you intend and sometimes it is not possible.

E.g. You perform your original SELECT on a table that contains a mix of numeric and non-numeric data.  Since no index exists that supports the select Oracle will need to do a full table scan.  It therefore needs to look at every record in `TestTable` and convert `sesid` to a number.  But it can't for the non-numeric values, and so it throws an exception even though you didn't want the record that was non-numeric.

**Final Aside:**

Object names in Oracle are not case sensitive (unless you use "quotes" to state that they should be) so general practice is to use identifiers with underscores instead of camel case so that they are easier to read when output by Oracle.

E.g. `test_table` rather than `TestTable`

Comment: `SESID = '12345'` will always be false (and it is the same for `SESID = TO_CHAR(12345)`) as the column storing `SESID` is `CHAR(8 BYTE)` so if `SESID` is `12345` then this is stored as `12345___` (where `___` represents trailing spaces).

Comment: You know what, I'm so used to using varchar2 now that I didn't even notice the CHAR definition. Great spot @MT0

Comment: I still think the vote down is harsh though. A comment to correct would have sufficed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm sorry but I think a down vote is warranted and I will also down vote this answer and accept MT0's answer. Your first two SQL statements clearly do not solve the problem and your supporting comments do not tackle the main issue either. Thank you for your time.